# Java JTable scrolling actions

Tags: java

I am using a JTable in java for listing the values from database.

I need something like, I need to list few set of values in the JTable. And when we scroll down or scroll up using scroll pane of JTable,  next set of  values must be loaded from database. so that instead of loading all values, i can list few values and scrolling action will retrieve next range of values.

How can I do this? 
Can any one suggest me an idea for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a [TableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html), like subclassing [DefaultTableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html). Need to track which rows you already retrieved from database and when table request the table model more rows, grab from database. This will occurs as user scrolls the table. Be careful if the total number of rows is huge, as you should discard rows retrieved and not shown currently in the table to save memory.

This question is not easy and implementations could vary. You can maintain an open connection and read from the `ResultSet`, you can open a new connection each time... If retrieving the rows takes too much time, the user will experience the scroll "freezes" while retrieving the new rows. Another problem is calculating the total number of rows, as table needs it for several operations (calculate the scrolling available...), implementing `getRowCount()` could be problematic with very large queries. You should perform a SELECT COUNT before to get the total number of rows and then perform the SELECT to start grabbing they.

Mi advice is to retrieve all rows from database and pass to the table. If the total number of rows is not too much large (<10000), `JTable` handles without problem such number of rows (some memory is required!) and the scroll will be perfectly smooth and only one database access is performed. If you know user already will not scroll the entire set of rows, try to adopt another technique, like limiting the total number of rows returned from database, setting a filter and getting all the rows (limited for example to 100) and show all in the table in order to avoid memory usage and database access.

In the days of Java 1.4.1 and Pentium IV (2004), we use to populate the `JTable` with all rows returned from database, limiting they to 10000 (WHERE ROWNUM < 10000 in Oracle) and the application needs more memory but works fine and smooth. The time required to retrieve all the rows was larger, but use a waiting dialog and let the user wait for the data (or he/she can filter the data to retrieve fewer rows).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do it with the scroll action. You could have next and back buttons instead. You could initially show the first set of values. Clicking on next or back will cause the next set to be retrieved. You might need some reference to the first and last value in the displayed list.

Comment: Hi... Thanks... Can you kindly suggest me some sample code which explains the above action...